# How to define macros for native code inside a build type in gradle?

Tags: c, android-studio, gradle, android-ndk, macros

I've built a library with native code in Android Studio. It has some time dependent parts (in C) that must be under certain levels of latency, and I need to measure them. So I've implemented some measurement routines. However, I don't want the measurement routines to work in a release compilation.

So I have defined macros that will allow me to compile or not code based on the build type:

In my native code:

```
#ifdef MEASURE
measureRoutine1();
if (MEASURE == 1) {
    measureRoutine2();
}
#endif
```

In my gradle file:

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.storeSignature
            debuggable false
            jniDebuggable false
            versionNameSuffix "2.3"
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            jniDebuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            versionNameSuffix '2.3.1'
        }
        measure1 {
            initWith debug
            externalNativeBuild {
                cmake {
                    cppFlags += "-DMEASURE=0"
                    cFlags += "-DMEASURE=0"
                }
            }
        }
        measure2 {
            initWith debug
            externalNativeBuild {
                cmake {
                    cppFlags += "-DMEASURE=1"
                    cFlags += "-DMEASURE=1"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Now, my problem is that it doesn't matter what buildType I compile, the MEASURE flag is not defined in my native code, so the measuring code never gets compiled.

**What am I doing wrong? How can I achieve what I need?**

*PS:
The only way I get the MEASURE macro to be defined in native is if I put the cFlags, outside the buildTypes in the defaultConfig space.
This following code works, but I need to hardcode the MEASURE macro every time I want to compile with measurements.*

```
defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 6
        versionName "2.3"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags "-std=c++11 -fexceptions -O2 -ffast-math -DMEASURE=0"
                cFlags "-O2 -ffast-math -DMEASURE=0"
            }
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE 1:**

If I define the MEASURE macro under the buildType release (only under release or both under release and debug) the macro appears defined in my native code with de value defined in release. It seems that it only isn't defined under the debug build type. Any ideas of what might be happening?

*I'm using Android Studio 2.3.3 with the latest stable updates up to date. Also, I've created a new test project to check if my old project is bugged, but same story in both.*

**UPDATE 2:**

I'm starting to think that maybe Android Studio is not building the right buildType. Another funny thing is happening, I have tried defining a boolean build config field for java inside the debug buildType, and even though the auto generated BuildConfig.java has the field set to true, at execution time with debug I get an error that the variable does not exist (unless I put the variable under the release buildType). So it looks like no matter what I select in my build variants, it is always building the release build type.

Here is my full test project build gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            versionNameSuffix '2.3.1'
            externalNativeBuild {
                cmake {
                    cppFlags += "-DMEASURE=0"
                    cFlags += "-DMEASURE=0"
                }
            }
            buildConfigField "Boolean", "DEBUG_MODE", "Boolean.parseBoolean(\"true\")"
        }    
    }

    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path 'src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Here is the auto-generated BuildConfig.java file:

```
public final class BuildConfig {
  public static final boolean DEBUG = Boolean.parseBoolean("true");
  public static final String APPLICATION_ID = "com.company.TestApp";
  public static final String BUILD_TYPE = "debug";
  public static final String FLAVOR = "";
  public static final int VERSION_CODE = 1;
  public static final String VERSION_NAME = "1.02.3.1";
  // Fields from build type: debug
  public static final Boolean DEBUG_MODE = Boolean.parseBoolean("true");
}
```

And here is the error I get at execution time when I use BuildConfig.DEBUG_MODE in my code:

```
Error:(14, 27) error: cannot find symbol variable DEBUG_MODE
```

What might be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution:

The problem is not how the macros are defined, that works fine, the problem is gradle.

There is [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36967265) when compiling libraries: Basically, every time you use make project, all the projects beside the 'app' project are compiled in their release version no matter what build variants are selected for them.

So in this case, the problem is that even though I select debug in the build variants box for my 'nativelibrary' module, the release build type is compiled + whatever I've selected for the 'app' build variant.

**The solution:**

Add the following code to the 'nativelibrary' gradle file:

```
defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"  

        //DEFINE THE DEFAULT PUBLISH CONFIG WHICH IS RELEASE
        defaultPublishConfig 'release'

        //ALLOW IT TO PUBLISH A NON DEFAULT WHICH WILL BE THE DEBUG OR
        //A CUSTOM BUILD TYPE
        publishNonDefault true

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
```

Replace the compile project(':nativelib') the following code to the app build gradle:

```
dependencies {

    //ERASE THE FOLLOWING LINE
    //compile project(':nativelib')

    //ADD BUILD TYPE SPECIFIC COMPILE TYPES AND REQUEST A SPECIFIC 
    //CONFIGURATION FOR THE 'nativelibrary' DEPENDING ON THE 
    //REQUESTED BUILD TYPE.
    releaseCompile project(path: ':nativelib', configuration: "release")
    debugCompile project(path: ':nativelib', configuration: "debug")


    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

This fixed my problem and now the macros are being created for debug.